# Error on implementing generic Repository for CRUD operations using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, generics

I have a problem, I want to get table from my generic class:

```
public virtual TEntity GetById(int id)
{
    return _db.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefault(c => ((IEntity)c).Code == id);
}
```

But `Linq` can't cast `IEntity`

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<TEntity, M> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class where M : new()
```

If a replace `TEntity : class` with `TEntity : IEntity` I get this error :

> The type 'TEntity' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Set()'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify two generic constraints, what you already have (`class`) to specify the type argument must be a reference type, and an interface constraint to specify that `TEntity` must implement your `IEntity` interface:

```
                                                                                               ^^here^^
public abstract class BaseRepository<TEntity, M> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity where M : new()
```

After that you should be able to do this:

```
public virtual TEntity GetById(int id)
{
   return _db.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Code == id);
}
```

But anyway I want to suggest if you're creating a generic repository, your `GetById` method should be "more flexible", for example you could do the following:

```
public virtual TEntity Find(params object[] keyValues)
{
   return _db.Set<TEntity>().Find(keyValues);
}
```